# Unable to run RaspiStill from PHP

Tags: camera, php

I have been attempting to use RaspiStill in PHP for a number of days now. I have searched around and have been unable to come up with a solution.

I have been attempting to use `shell_exec()` in my php file like so:

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/raspistill -rot 180 -q 70 -w 1920 -h 1080  -o /media/64GB/www/timelapse/image_image.jpg 2>&1")
```

Which works if you use it from the console and type:

```
php php_script.php
```

At first I was getting this error when running the php script in the browser:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

This was resolved by updating `/etc/sudoers` with:

```
Defaults:www-data !requiretty
```

I also added this line:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

No error is returned in the apache logs so I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: What else is in your PHP script?  The shell_exec command shown doesn't use `sudo`, so I don't see how the sudo error you received is related to that command.

Comment: was this ever resolved? I'm encountering the same issue and have tried every suggestion but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

If you find your apache web service is unable to run the raspistill command you may need to modify the www-data apache user to allow it to run the command:

```
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="vchiq",GROUP="video",MODE="0660"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/10-vchiq-permissions.rules
```

and this one

```
usermod -a -G video www-data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the "-n" param to your raspistill command to disable previews, see if that helps. You may also try "-t 0" to reduce wait time.

Comment: That didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Found a tutorial for something similar that helped me: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=56209&hilit=+php

The part that helped me in particular was: 

sudo chmod 777 /var/www
sudo chmod 777 /dev/vchiq

after entering those commands Shell_exec would successfully invoke raspistill.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by using the following:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/vchiq
```

and

```
usermod -a -G video www-data
```